# vs code key binding (run python script in terminal) no longer working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, key-bindings

For some time now I have had a key binding within VS Code that runs the python script I am working on in the terminal.

This has so far been working without issues, until today when I start getting the following error:

Warn: Cannot read property 'toCommandArgument' of undefined

I am using Anaconda environments and have tried updating to latest version of vscode (1.19.3) this did not fix my issues though.

I have not changed environments or changed the code. it just stopped working

So far I have tried removing and reassigning the key binding to another key sequence, with same result.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: If you're running the `2018.1.0` version of the Python extension then it may be due to a change in the latest release. If you are running the latest release then please report a bug at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python .

Answer (score 2):

*I have nearly the same symptom. After last extensions update (it was MS-Python 2018.1.0 and GitHistory 0.4.0 updates) my keybinding for "Run Python File in Terminal" started to drop-down warning: "Path must be a string. Received undefined". In the same time running file by context menu was still OK. After some googling I tried to delete my custom user setting "python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true, which by default is False. After that warning changed to "Cannot read property 'toCommandArgument' of undefined" as Henrik says.*

Edit:
Insiders build fixes this issue:
https://pvsc.blob.core.windows.net/extension-builds/ms-python-insiders.vsix

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack Overflow. This does not look like an answer to the original question, it is more of a "Me too" comment that is not an answer.

Comment: I'd removed the word 'nearly', the solution is to install the insiders build or wait for the new release in late Feb. IMHO this answer is valid.